# Liquibase: how is the loadUpdateData rolled back?

Tags: sql, rollback, liquibase

The **Liquibase** documentation claims that the [`loadUpdateData`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/load_update_data) refactoring action can be rolled back automatically. When faced with a scenario where some of the records during that operation were created anew and some were actually updated, with old values obviously overwritten, how does the **Liquibase** handle the rollback?

It's especially curious since automatic rollback is supported neither for [`loadData`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/load_data), nor for [`updateData`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/update_data), but is supposed to be somehow magically possible for [`loadUpdateData`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/load_update_data), which one would expect to be more complicated to implement than both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support automatic rollback. See [Liquibase Documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_update_data.html)